# Spring container , web container?

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have moderate understanding of Spring Framework, and  in various books I read that Spring acts as a `container`.

Q1) What does it mean to say that Spring is a `container`?

Q2) Does spring as a `container` provide services like `transactional`, `connection pooling` etc.

Q3) what difference are in containers `spring container` vs `web container` -> It might be totally irrelevant comparsion, but if anyone can help me get this understand, really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

In spring: Spring container contains beans (Java objects that are subject to dependency-injection). It provides the space for residing these beans and maintains the life-cycle of the Java beans.
this is referred as Spring IOC container because of it provides Spring Inversion of Control.

You can learn more about Spring IOC container at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Web Container, Specially Servlet containers contain servlets, filters, listeners, etc. and manages their state and lifecycle.That is the place where you can deploy your java based web applications.(any java web app e.g:- JSP/Servlet based web app, spring based web app etc...)

So keep it remember that these are two different things.